# Getting path in iPhotoLibrary by photo id using applescript

Tags: image, path, applescript, iphoto

I try to select the path in the iPhotoLibrary of a photo by its id using the following Applescript:

*tell application "iPhoto" 
   set photoID to 25801
   set thePhoto to photo id (photoID + 2 ^ 32)
   set photoPath to image path of thePhoto
end tell*

That doesn't work because Applescript told me, that it's not possible to convert 4.294993097E+9 to integer. I wrote *(photoID + 2 ^ 32) as number* and Applescript wasn't able to got the image path.

Please told me what was my mistake and how can I solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You must first get the 'Photo' object from the ID by a search in iPhoto, then only get the path of that object:

```
set myPhoto to first item of (every photo whose id is myId)
set myPath to image path of myPhoto
```

myPath is the complete file path in Unix format (with'/' and not ':')